# Как вывести данные ИЗ ObservableList в таблицу Mysql.Java

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, observablecollection

Как вывести данные ИЗ ObservableList в таблицу Mysql.Java

---

MySql WorkBench
данные передаю через PreparedStatement

Comment: Что используете для работы с базой?

Comment: MySql WorkBench данные передаю через PreparedStatement

Comment: Тогда все просто. ObservableList тот же List, проходите по нему циклом и передайте элементы в sql запрос.

Comment: Можно пожалуйста пример а то я не могу разобраться .Спасибо большое.

Comment: for (SomethingInList element : observableList) { mysql.send(element);
}.

Comment: и еще один вопрос почему не сохраняется отредактированный текст в таблице после нажатия Enter?Colum.isEditable(true) стоит и таблица тоже.В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
    import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
    import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;

    public class OListTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("URL", "USER", "PASS");) {
                ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Трям", "Пам", "Пам", "Трям");
                try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("insert into TARAM(val) values(?)")) {
                    for (String s : observableList) {
                        preparedStatement.setString(1, s);
                        preparedStatement.addBatch();
                    }
                    preparedStatement.executeBatch();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```